# Response Time of getting data from server is too late

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working in Codeigniter(PHP Framework).In my website, I am listing "users list" which is around 10,00,000 records.I had applied pagination with limit 10 records per page.When I load webpage I get following error "Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted".I had got the solution to set "ini_set('Memory_limit', '-1');" in my controller or configure in php.ini file.But now the issue is after configuring "ini_set('Memory_limit', '-1');" in my controller, the response time of getting data from the server is too late.

I have created dynamic query to fetch user data.It is some how look like as below :

```
SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT user_id from tbl_login_track WHERE user_id=U.user_id ORDER BY created_date desc LIMIT 1) as user,(SELECT created_date from tbl_login_track WHERE user_id=U.user_id ORDER BY created_date desc LIMIT 1) as user_login_date,DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,(SELECT created_date from tbl_login_track WHERE user_id=U.user_id ORDER BY created_date desc LIMIT 1)) as last_login,PP.product_plan_name , U.*,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_product WHERE user_id = U.user_id) AS product_post_count FROM tbl_user as U JOIN tbl_product_plan as PP ON U.product_plan_id=PP.product_plan_id LEFT JOIN tbl_login_track as LT ON U.user_id=LT.user_id limit 0,10
```

**Required**: Want to decrease the query result time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Allowing unlimited memory is never a solution. You must have an error in your pagination sql as 10 record limit should never cause memory to be exhausted. You need to find the memory leak. Without any code, it is a shot in the dark.

Comment: I had check my query.There is no issue in that.and "need to find the memory leak" means?

Comment: You need to find why bytes are getting exhausted when fetching a meer 10 records... This isnt normal.

Comment: If you post your code you may actually stand a chance at someone being able to help you out.

Comment: 1st error you are outputing is an PHP error about memory. That's most likely code related. 2nd, in order to improve your query, we need to see the schema. The query can be simplified or the tables may lack relations, theres no way of knowing

Answer (score 1):

I have created dynamic query to fetch user data.It is some how look like as below :

```
SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT user_id from tbl_login_track WHERE user_id=U.user_id ORDER BY created_date desc LIMIT 1) as user,(SELECT created_date from tbl_login_track WHERE user_id=U.user_id ORDER BY created_date desc LIMIT 1) as user_login_date,DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,(SELECT created_date from tbl_login_track WHERE user_id=U.user_id ORDER BY created_date desc LIMIT 1)) as last_login,PP.product_plan_name , U.*,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_product WHERE user_id = U.user_id) AS product_post_count FROM tbl_user as U JOIN tbl_product_plan as PP ON U.product_plan_id=PP.product_plan_id LEFT JOIN tbl_login_track as LT ON U.user_id=LT.user_id limit 0,10
```